# C# - Foreach Loop working when walking through code, but does not when run

Tags: c#, foreach

I have a list of a custom class, (called `enemy`), named `enemyList`. I use a foreach loop. Inside, I generate a random number between 1 and 200,000. Then I save it to a list outside of the foreach loop:

```
  try
  {
  List<int> randoms = new List<int>();
  foreach (enemy m in enemyList)
  {
     Random r = new Random();
     int i = r.Next(1, 2000);
     randoms.Add(i);
  }
```

Then, when that is done, under the foreach loop,  I do this:

```
int highest = randoms.Max();
int rate = -1;
```

Next, I use another foreach loop to figure out which value in `randoms` equals the highest number.

```
  foreach (int number in randoms)
   {
       rate++;
       if (highest == number)
       {
           return rate;
       }
   }
   }
   catch (Exception)
   {

     return 0;
   }
```

When I run it, it displays which item is the highest, (example: if it is the first in the `randoms` list, then display `0`). But for some reason, it always returns 0. But if I walk through the code, it works properly. Can anyone explain why this happens so I can fix it?

Comment: Try declaring `r = new Random()` outside the loop. Each time you instantiate a new random, it reseeds.

Comment: To clarify a little, new Random() re-seeds with the current timestamp. If the loop runs at speed, you are easily re-seeding with the same timestamp every time, so all the random numbers will be the same.

Answer (score -3):

Are you trying to select a random item from your enemies list?

If so, you could just do something like this:

```
var rng = new Random();
var randomEnemy = enemyList[ rng.Next( enemyList.Count ) ];
```

If you are doing this rapidly you would want to declare your random number generator somewhere else so it isn't reseeding and constantly selecting the same value.

Comment: What? I have never seen code like that. =-(

Comment: In the above case, `var randomEnemy = enemyList[ rng.Next( enemyList.Count ) ];` will return a random enemy. `rng.Next( someInt )` will return a random positive integer that is less than someInt.


Then you can just use that randomly generated integer to directly access the enemy from the enemyList.